# select query to display Date format as DAY MMM DD YYYY in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I tried like this

```
SELECT DATENAME(DW,GETDATE()) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), SYSDATETIME(), 107)
```

result is

```
Thursday Dec 11, 2014
```

**Required OutPut:**

SELECT QUERY TO DISPLAY DATE AS SHOWN BELOW

```
Thu Dec 11, 2014
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(DW,GETDATE()),3) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), SYSDATETIME(), 107) 
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: He is using GETDATE() and SYSDATETIME(), so no need of FROM here

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to take only left 3 symbols of your day of the week name:

```
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(DW,GETDATE()),3) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), SYSDATETIME(), 107)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATENAME(DW,GETDATE())) + ' '
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), SYSDATETIME(), 107)
```

Comment: Is there any chance to make it much simpler.

Comment: No, It is jsut the way you already did to get the 'Dec 11, 2014'.